# How to get server ip address in Spring Boot Environment?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot Environment to get the server port as follows

```
@Autowired
Environment environment; 

environment.getProperty("local.server.port")
```

It works

However, I can't figure out how to get the ip

I tried these

```
environment.getProperty("local.server.address") 
environment.getProperty("local.server.ip") 
environment.getProperty("local.server.host")  
// and many other combinations but can't make it to work
```

What is the property name for the ip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For port you want:

```java
environment.getProperty("server.port");
```

And for the IP the server is listening on you want:

```java
environment.getProperty("server.address");
```

As an aside, you can use `@Value` to inject it directly into a String field without using `Environment` like so:

```java
@Value("${server.address}")
private String serverAddress;
```

Comment: Thank you but it gives me `null`. Why? This works `local.server.port` but this gives null `local.server.address` and this gives null `server.address`

Comment: I think if you're not setting it explicitly in configuration it'll be null. I say that cause there's no default in [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

What IP address are you looking for? The IP of the host the app is running on?